# Laravel Ajax Post Exception

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a select box. And i'm redirecting clients via select box. When they select they are redirecting.

Before i started to write code with laravel my system was working. After laravel i have a problem with this matter.

```
$('#parent_products').change(function(){
            productid = $(this).val();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('redirectVariant') }}',
                data: {
                    productid : productid,
                    _method   : 'PATCH'
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    alert('Hata \n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location.replace(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

I'm getting this error.

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

This is my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ajax'], function () {
        Route::post('product/redirect_variant', [
            'uses' =>'AjaxController@redirectVariant',
            'as'   => 'redirectVariant',
        ]);
    });
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectVariant(Request $request){
        dd(Request::all());
    }
}
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript is spoofing a PATCH request, while your route is setup for POST.

You could try:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'ajax'],     function () {
    Route::patch('product/redirect_variant', [
        'uses' =>'AjaxController@redirectVariant',
        'as'   => 'redirectVariant',
    ]);
});
```